# Pick m numbers from array of n numbers so their total differences are minimum

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, knapsack-problem

There are n towers with variable number of floors in an ancient city. We have to build floors on them so that at least m out of n towers (n>=m) are of equal height. Write a function to calculate the minimum number of floors that need to be built for m floors to be of equal height.

Example: Given an array (1,5,4,2,1) each element representing the number of floors in that tower and m=3, the function should return 2 as we have to build 1 floor each to towers on index 0 & 4 so 3 towers will be of equal height. Function definition below

```
public Integer calcMinFloors(Integer[] towers, int m);
```

Comment: "for m floors to be of equal height" should be "for m towers" shouldn't it? Also "There are m towers" should be "There are n towers" maybe

Comment: Could you please edit your question? I see `k`, `n`,  `m`.. which one is what exactly? I mean I can think of how this is probably meant... But I find it confusing and it would be nicer if the reader does not have to figure out what is probably meant...

Comment: Fixed the question now. Thanks for the corrections

Answer (score 3):

Updating the answer from @gnasher729:

Straightforward solution for `n` element array:

1. Sort in descending order: `(5,4,2,1,1)`
2. Loop over elements and for each element look ahead `m-1` next elements. Sum the differences and save the minimum. Time complexity `O(n*m)`

Slightly more advanced solution:

1. Sort in descending order: `(5,4,2,1,1)`
2. Get first element `(5)`, look ahead `m-1` elements `(4,2)`, count how many floors you need `(1 + 3 = 4)`and save the result as `best` and as `current`
3. Loop over array from element 2. for each element `i` calculate the value: `current = current - (arr[i-1] - arr[i])*(m-1) + arr[i]-arr[i+m-1]`. Save to `best` if it's smaller than it.

That should give time complexity `O(n*log(n))` for sorting + `O(n)` for steps 2-3.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is solvable is time **O(NlogN)** and constant space **O(1)**, where **N** is the number of towers.

We have to make `m` towers of equal height such that we have to build minimum floors.

**Important Observations**

**1**. Because we are building minimum floors,rather than building floors on `m` towers and reach equal height, we will try to make `m - 1` towers to be of equal height of a target tower.

**2**. The optimal solution lies in finding such `m` towers which have the minimum sum of heights difference.Let the solution be towers having following floors in **ascending order**:

```
m1 , m2 , m3 , ....... m floor
```

The optimal solution has the following property:

The sum of the differences **is minimum**:

```
(m - m1) + (m - m2) + (m - m3) + .....(m - (m-1))
```

Because only then we can say that we need to build minimum number of floors.

**So it turns out we need to find set of m floors such that the difference of their heights from the floor with maximum height(within those m towers) is minimum**.

Say we have array `arr` of length n, depicting the number of floors on each tower.First we `sort` the towers by their height.

Then we start finding the sum of the `differences` in following way.Say we are at `index i` in . We find the following sum:

```
arr[i + m - 1] - arr[i]
         +
arr[i + m - 2] - arr[i]
         +
arr[i + m - 3] - arr[i]
         +
arr[i + m - 4] - arr[i]
         .
         .
         .
arr[i + 1] - arr[i]
```

Lets call the sum `s1`. Now when we consider the next set of `m` towers , meaning towers from indices `i + 1` to `i + m`, **we do not need a loop to compute the sum of differences, it can simply be derived from following**:

```
(m - 1)*arr[i + m] - s1 - ((m-1)*arr[i])
```

So using this simple mathematical technique, we only need a single for loop for this problem.

The pseudocode for the proposed algorithm is:

```
Sort the array arr of n towers.

Compute the sum of differences for first set of m towers.

sum = 0

for(i = 1 to m - 1)
{
  sum = sum + arr[i] - arr[0]
}

Now for the remaining set of m towers

previous_sum = sum, sum = 0, j = 1
minimum_sum = previous_sum
for(i = m to n - 1)
{

 sum = (m-1)*arr[i] - previous_sum - (m - 1)*arr[j - 1]
 increment j

 if( sum < minimum_sum )
 {
  minimum_sum = sum
 }

 previous_sum = sum
}

The answer is minimum_sum.
```

Comment: @dingalapadum Please tell me the example for which it is wrong. I will happily remove my answer.

Comment: {1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6}. m=9

Comment: Correct answer is 8 for the case Towers = (1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6) and m=9. I still don't understand the solution though.

Comment: @crazyim5 Rather than building 1 floor on each of the 8 towers of height 5, we build only 4 floors on first tower of height 1.

Comment: @crazyim5 What is it that you don't understand.

Comment: @crazyim5 How can the correct solution be 8?Kindly clarify. You are contradicting your own question.

Comment: @Dante, thanks for explaining that. You are right, the correct answer for that situation is 4 as we can add 4 extra floors to 1 and have 9 towers of same height.

Answer (score 0):

You sort by height in ascending or descending order, and the rest is trivial.

Comment: What is the complexity of trivial part btw? Straightforward approach gave me O(n*m), Is there anything better?